# Как синхронизировать почту на сервере и в моем приложении, использую IMAP(MailKit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, imap, mailkit

Пишу своего почтового клиента используя библиотеку MailKit.
Проблема возникла такая: я кеширую сообщения в локальную бд, для быстродействия работы. Как мне потом при следующем входе синхронизировать кеш в бд и данные на сервере. Может какой то флаг у сообщений есть, что сообщение изменено(ну, например прочитано). Или как понимать, что сообщение удалено было напрямую в почте и мне как то надо это понять и удалить в своем кеше.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в интернете ничего найти подобного не могу.

Answer (score 0):

На стороне Imap клиентов нет такой опции как уведомлять о прочтение смс, изменение статуса сообщений. Но есть папки прочитано\не прочитано. Как вариант если только вам проверять папку прочитанные и обрабатывать их

```
//1. Создать объект ImapClient и подключиться к серверу:
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    client.Connect("imap.example.com", 993, true);

    // Аутентификация на сервере
    client.Authenticate("username", "password");

    // Код для проверки папки "Прочитанные"

    // Отключение от сервера
    client.Disconnect(true);
}


//2. Получить объект IMailFolder для папки "Прочитанные":
var folder = client.GetFolder("Прочитанные");


//3. Получить количество сообщений в папке:
var count = folder.Count;


//4. Получить список UID всех сообщений в папке:
var uids = folder.Search(SearchQuery.All).ToList();


//5. Получить список UID всех прочитанных сообщений в папке:
var uids = folder.Search(SearchQuery.Seen).ToList();


//6. Получить список объектов MimeMessage для всех сообщений в папке:
var messages = new List<MimeMessage>();
foreach (var uid in uids)
{
    var message = folder.GetMessage(uid);
    messages.Add(message);
}


//7. Получить список объектов MimeMessage для всех прочитанных сообщений в папке:
var messages = new List<MimeMessage>();
foreach (var uid in uids)
{
    var message = folder.GetMessage(uid);
    if (message.Flags.HasFlag(MessageFlags.Seen))
    {
        messages.Add(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вот, например, я закешировал 100 сообщений. пользователь на сервере удалил 10, чтоб это понять, мне надо только путем получения всех id на сервере и потом в лоб сравнивать с бдшными значениями?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов верно, но опять же таки если человек использует только ваш клиент, то это не проблема, можно напрямую действия обрабатывать. Если же он в браузере или где-то ещё удалил смс, то только в лоб можно обработать.